# Don't see my custom Initializer for UIImageView

Tags: objective-c, uiimageview, initialization

I create new UIImageView class (name customUIImageView), in .h file add:

```
+ (instancetype)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame imageName:(NSString*)imageName;
```

In another class when I want to use my custom class in init I don't see my custom initializer, I try

```
self.greenIm = [[customUIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:frame // here I don't see my imageName
```

What I do wrong ?

Comment: Yes of course I import and don't receive any errors but I can use only standard initWithFrame.

Comment: I try and receive error - No visible interface bla bla bla

Comment: please see my answer this will solve your problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using + u are creating a class method, so can access it like this

```
[customUIImageView initWithFrame:frame imageName:imageName];
```

May be it can help u